# How to publish database on RackSpace dedicated server?

Tags: mysql, database, publishing

I have made database in MYSql on local WampServer.

Now i want to publish this database on RackSpace dedicated server.

> EDITED :

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on the dedicated server. I want to know how to make connection between the webservice i have made on my local machine? I have written code for MYSQL , so will it change for SQLServer 2008  ?

I have no idea of publishing database on dedicated server.

I have searched for this ,but didnt get any solution.

How can i do this?

Please help me.

Thanks..

Comment: can't you script your database and run your scripts on the Rackspace server ?

Comment: is making connection by MYSqlConnection to SqlServer 2008 database valid?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

to create a full backup of your local version, ZIP the data file (especially if it's large), then use the

mysql

command line to re-create the database from the dump file.

From the linked docs:

> A common use of mysqldump is for making a backup of an entire
>   database:
>
> shell> mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql You can load the dump file
>   back into the server like this:
>
> shell> mysql db_name < backup-file.sql
>
> Or like this:
>
> shell> mysql -e "source /path-to-backup/backup-file.sql" db_name
>
> mysqldump is also very useful for populating databases by copying data
>   from one MySQL server to another:
>
> shell> mysqldump --opt db_name | mysql --host=remote_host -C db_name

Comment: thanks for reply. I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on the dedicated server. But i want to know how to make connection between the webservice i have made on my local machine? I have written code for MYSQL , so will it change for SQLServer 2008 that i have installed  ?